# Could clean/cultured meat be ethically OK for vegetarians but not vegans?

Tags: is-it-vegetarian, cultured-meat

[Clean/cultured meat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultured_meat) doesn't harm any animal and is grown industrially.

Could clean/cultured meat fit into a Vegetarian's diet? Cultured meat's an animal product created using animal cells and therefore it can't fit into a vegan's diet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is eating lab-grown meat vegan?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/227/is-eating-lab-grown-meat-vegan)

Comment: I retracted my close vote because the question was edited to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official body dictating what vegetarians may and may not eat. Each needs to make his or her own decision. I don't think that I would eat it since I am quite happy with traditional vegetarian options. However, if meat eaters switch to it then I would be pleased.